# Cannot propagate events from QgsMapCanvas to QgsMapCanvasItem

Tags: qgis, mapping, c++

I've extended the QgsMapCanvas  to catch mouse events and all works well.
Then I try to catch events from a QgsMapCanvasItem. Reading the classes QgsMapCanvas extends QgraphicsView, and QgsMapCanvasItem extends a QGraphicsItem so in Qt is very simple to pass events from QgraphicsView to QGraphicsItem , but it seems impossible from Qgis using C++

Here is my code:

```
    class HciCanvas : public QgsMapCanvas
{

  Q_OBJECT

public:
    HciCanvas(QWidget * grafD);
    ~HciCanvas();

    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) override;
```

and in .CPP

```
void HciCanvas::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event){
qDebug() << "HciCanvas::mousePressEvent in screen X:" << event->pos().x() << " Y: " << event->pos().y();
    QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);  // to propagate events !!!!
    QgsMapCanvas::mousePressEvent(event);
}
```

Then the graphics Item :

```
class PpiItem : public QgsMapCanvasItem
{

public:
    PpiItem(QgsMapCanvas * canv, QPixmap * pixmap);
    ~PpiItem();

    void setCenter(const QgsPointXY &point);
    QgsPointXY center() const { return _pixmapSourceCenter; };

   void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override;
```

and in CPP

```
void PpiItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    qDebug("PpiItem::mousePressEvent");
}
```

Finally in mainwindow.cpp

```
pixmap = new QPixmap(":/img/boat.png");
     myMapCanvas = new HciCanvas(this);
     myMapCanvas->resize(QSize(1280,1024));
     myMapCanvas->enableAntiAliasing(true);
     myMapCanvas->setCanvasColor(QColor(189,210,255));   //background
     myMapCanvas->freeze(false);
     myMapCanvas->setVisible(true);

 
    // set canvaswidget
     this->setCentralWidget(myMapCanvas);

     //loading world shape
     LoadShapeWorldLayer();

     //test loading a raster
     LoadRasterLayer();

     //Add layers list to MAP LAYER REGISTRY
     QgsProject::instance()->addMapLayers(myMapLayers);

     // Set the Map Canvas Layer Set
     myMapCanvas->setLayers(myMapLayers);


     item = new PpiItem(myMapCanvas, pixmap);
     QPointF centre;
     centre.setX(9);
     centre.setY(44);
     item->setCenter(centre);
```

This code produces a Framework with a map. If I click on the map the events in HciCanvas is catch and I see the call to in log "HciCanvas::mousePressEvent..."
If I click on the PpiItem ( the boat.png) I see only the call to `HciCanvas::mousePressEvent` but not the call to `PpiItem::mousePressEvent`.

why this strange behavior?

Look the code below ! It works like charme in Qt so i think it is a QGIS problem !

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QGraphicsItem>

class CustomView : public QGraphicsView
{
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom view clicked.";
        QGraphicsView::mousePressEvent(event);
    }
};


class CustomItem : public QGraphicsItem
{
public:

    CustomItem(QString n, int v ){ name = n; value = v;};

    QRectF boundingRect() const override
    {
        qreal penWidth = 1;
        return QRectF(-value - penWidth / 2, -10 - penWidth / 2,
                      20 + penWidth, 20 + penWidth);
    }

    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
               QWidget *widget) override
    {
        painter->drawRoundedRect(-value, -10, 20, 20, 5, 5);
    }



protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) override
    {
        qDebug() << "Custom item clicked." << name;


    }

   private:

    QString name;
    int value;
};



int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    CustomItem item("Asko",10);


    QGraphicsScene scene(0, 0, 100, 100);
    scene.addItem(&item);

    CustomItem item2("Jeremias",70);
    scene.addItem(&item2);

    CustomView view;
    view.setScene(&scene);
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this answer will be helpful to you although for Python not C++ https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/442985/get-properties-of-qgsvertexmarker-upon-mouse-click/442995#442995

Comment: see this post, but consider that using C++ .. this code works like a charm, so I think it is a Qgis Problem ! Look the code I've added to the last part of the question...